# getAttribute return unresolved

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm just trying to save the attribute of an input value to a variable.

This is the code:

```
var sliderNumber = element.all(by.model('color.red')).get(1);
var firstNum = sliderNumber.getAttribute('value').then(function(value) {
    return value;
});
  //Some code that changes the  sliderNumber attribute      
expect(sliderNumber.getAttribute('value')).toEqual(firstNum + 1);
```

This gives me an error like this:

> Expected '184' to equal Promise::433 ([[PromiseStatus]]: "pending")1.

I've also tried:

```
var firstNum = function() {
    return sliderNumber.getAttribute('value').then(function(value) {
        return value;
    });
}
```

That didn't help at all. How do I resolve this promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `.getAttribute()` returns a promise, which will invoke your callback asynchronously, you need to put your test logic within the callback:

```
var sliderNumber = element.all(by.model('color.red')).get(1);

// get the initial value
sliderNumber.getAttribute('value').then(function(value) {
    // once we've got the initial value, store it, then proceed with your test
    var initialValue = parseInt(value, 10);

    //Some code that changes the  sliderNumber attribute  

    expect(sliderNumber.getAttribute('value')).toEqual((initialValue + 1).toString());
});
```

You can't simply get the return value outside of the callback, because that callback may or may not be called after the rest of your code.

Comment: Oh interesting. So any of the test that has to do with that initial value I'm getting has to go inside the `.then` function?

Comment: I'd also like to add one thing to your code. In your expect statement, `.getAttribute` only returns a string or null so it should be `.toEqual((parseInt(initialValue) + 1).toString())`

Comment: Right, you could either put your tests directly in the `.then()` portion, or break them out into individual functions, which you can call in `.then()`. And thanks for the edit, I forgot to ensure things were of the correct type! I've made another small tweak to make it easier to read (`parseInt` further up) and a bit more solid ([always pass radix parameter to `parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)).

Comment: What if I wanted to do `browser.wait()` until `.getAttribute('aria-expanded')` returned true. Do I put the test inside the `.then()` which is inside `browser.wait()`? I don't think that would make sense would it?